# How to limit group items to 1 item and make the group item box larger

Tags: html, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am trying to develop my first windows 8 store app.  I am using the split app template.  I need to reduce the grouped items to a single selection and I need to make the box larger.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I believe I figured it out.

In the `items.css`, I increased the size of the width property of the `.itimepage .itemslist .items` tag.  Additionally, I increased the width of the `.itempage .itemslist .item .item-overlay .item-subtitle` tag.